$\mathbb E(\max(X_1,...,X_{t+1})|\mathcal{F}_t)$ where the $X_i$ are iid uniform

Let $X_1,...,X_T$ be independent and identically distributed uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. Let $$M_t:=\max\{X_1,...,X_t\},$$
$L_t=M_t-ct$ for a $c>0$ and $L_0:=-\infty$. If $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(L_0,...,L_t)$, what I want to compute is $$\sigma=\inf \{t\geq 0 : L_t\geq\mathbb E(L_{t+1}|F_t)\}.$$

I wanted to start with $$\mathbb E(M_{t+1}-ct|\mathcal{F}_t)=\mathbb E(\max(X_1,...,X_{t+1})|\mathcal{F}_t)-ct.$$
But what is $\mathbb E(\max(X_1,...,X_{t+1})|\mathcal{F}_t)$? How do I compute this conditional expectation? I feel like it involves the probability that $X_{t+1}>X_i$ for all $i=1,...,t$ but I can't come up with a closed form.
Can someone help?

We have $X_n\perp\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$ and $M_{n-1}$ is $\mathscr{F}_{n-1}$-measurable (because $M_{n-1}=L_{n-1}+c(n-1)$). Also, $M_n=\max(X_n,M_{n-1})$. Therefore:
$$\begin{aligned}E[M_n|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]&=E[\max(X_n,M_{n-1})|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]\\
&=E[\max(X_n,y)]|_{y=M_{n-1}}
\end{aligned}$$
Now, since $y \in [0,1]$:
$$\int_0^1\max(u,y)du=y\int_0^ydu+\int_y^1udu=y^2+\frac{1-y^2}{2}=\frac{y^2+1}{2}$$
So $E[M_n|\mathscr{F}_{n-1}]=\frac{M_{n-1}^2+1}{2}$.

@Analysis yes sorry. What I wanted to say is: we can rewrite $\inf {n :L_n \geq E[L_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}n]}$ in terms of a stopping time depending on $M_n$ because $E[L{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n]$ can be expressed explicitly.

I see, thanks! I'll think about it further.
